# How to exit from inside of an matched expression, like "inside", in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

For parenthesis, bracket and braces, I can easily jump out of it using <kbd>C-M-u</kbd>.

However, for matched expression like `"", ''`, I could not find a good way to jump out.

Is there any commands for doing so? Thank you.

Comment: Which major mode are you using? `C-M-u` (`backward-up-list`) works fine for me within quoted strings in, for example, `js-mode`. Also, which version of Emacs?

Comment: @Chris I use Haskell and C++ mode on Emacs 24.3. I tested js-mode and it fails too. Did you mean you could jump out of `()` or `""`?

Comment: Using `|` to represent point, when at `foo("bar|")` one invocation of `backward-up-list` takes me to `foo(|"bar")`, and a second to `foo|("bar")`. I get the same behaviour in `c++-mode`. Emacs 24.4 on Ubuntu 14.04. Does it work for you from `emacs -Q`?

Comment: No it doesn't work either. It reports `Scan error: unbalanced parentheses`

Comment: Strange. I suppose it could be an issue between version 24.3 and 24.4.

Comment: Yeah it could be. I 'll search for trivial solution first before turn to re-compilation.

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921320/emacs-bulletproof-up-list