# How to rewrite a native defun in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

**Premises**:

My Emacs has a small bug (cannot go up from inside of `""`) in one of its original defun (`up-list`). This defun is vital to one of my frequently used command (`backward-up-list`) which is bound to <kbd>C-M-u</kbd>.

Therefore, I wanted to achieve below objectives:

1. Write a NEW defun named `my-up-list` which has the bug fix;
2. RE-write the native defun `backward-up-list` to call the above new defun (instead of the native buggy `up-list`). (By RE-writing under the same defun name, I intend to preserve its original convenient key bindings.)

By following the Emacs Tutorial [Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Change-a-defun.html), I implemented it as below:

1. I wrote a new defun `my-up-list` inside .emacs file; (see code in the end)
2. I rewrote the defun `backward-up-list` under a the same name inside .emacs file; (see code in the end).

However, when wI tested it out by trying it in `"|"` (| is the cursor position), I encounter below error:

> backward-up-list: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda nil (interactive) (let ((s (syntax-ppss))) (if (nth 3 s) (progn (goto-char (nth 8 s))))) (condition-case nil (progn (up-list)) (error nil))), 1 [2 times]

**Question:**

- Is it the correct way to re-write a native defun just by putting the
  new implementation with the same name in .emacs file?
- What may went wrong in my code?

**Reference**:
(The `my-up-list` is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921320/emacs-bulletproof-up-list))

```
;; I only changed "up-list" to "my-up-list" -modeller
(defun backward-up-list (&optional arg)
  "Move backward out of one level of parentheses.
With ARG, do this that many times.
A negative argument means move forward but still to a less deep spot.
This command assumes point is not in a string or comment."
  (interactive "^p")
  (my-up-list (- (or arg 1))))

;; copied from solution to another question - modeller
(defun my-up-list ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((s (syntax-ppss)))
    (when (nth 3 s)
      (goto-char (nth 8 s))))
  (ignore-errors (up-list)))
```

Comment: If the aim of redefining the function is to retain its keybindings, Emacs has you covered with command remapping. See `C-h i g` `(elisp) Remapping Commands` `RET`. Here you can use `(global-set-key [remap backward-up-list] 'my-backward-up-list)`.

Comment: @phils thanks for the tips. It is great to learn an alternative way for doing the trick.

Comment: It's not clear (to me at least) why you even want to do this. Vanilla `up-list` takes you out of the string, just past it. And invoking it again then takes you exactly where `my-up-list` takes you. So without `my-up-list` you just need to hit the `up-list` key twice to get the same effect. And as a bonus you can use `up-list` whenever you just want to get past the string. If you bind a command such as `(my-)up-list` to a key then you typically want it to be a simple, repeatable key anyway.

Comment: @Drew, I got a "scan error: unbalanced parentheses" from the vanilla version `up-list`. I uses (self-compiled Emacs 23.4 64-bit). Please see code here: http://lpaste.net/109513

Comment: Ah yes, there is an `up-list` bug in Emacs 23 and 24 (including the latest 24.4 pretest), and there is a different bug in Emacs 22 and prior. You could just pick up the definition from a recent Emacs 24.4 development snapshot, where the Emacs 23-24 bug has been fixed.

Comment: @Drew, OK I will check 24.4 out. I did not used snapshot on my Debian (Debian snapshot went down.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your my-up-list function needs to accept the same arguments as the original up-list, and call up-list with them?

Comment: You are correct.Btw, is there a trivial way to write `my-down-list` from `down-list` that does work symmetrical to `my-up-list`. I am still lisp illiterate.

Comment: I am an elisp neophyte myself. It sounds odd to me that you would need to do this kind of patching - have you asked on the emacs mailing list?

Comment: It seems the email-list page does not store email-list anymore. Anyway thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is with the "advice" system.  This provides some simple ways to wrap and extend existing functions.  There's a whole section in the elisp manual explaining how to do it.